# Getting solarized theme working with vim + vim-airline-themes

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I'm trying to get a vim-airline theme working with my vim, the theme I'm after is [solarized dark](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/wiki/Screenshots#solarized-dark).

The following is my `.vimrc` file:

```
 # .vimrc
 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

 call vundle#begin()

 Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
 Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
    <more plugins>
 call vundle#end()

 let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
 let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_sep = ' '
 let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_alt_sep = '|'
 let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'default'

 let g:airline_theme='solarized'
 let g:airline_solarized_bg='dark'
```

And the following is what my editor looks like currently:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: What terminal are you using? In order for most solarized themes to work, you need to set the terminal theme itself to something solarized, basically so that the colors are available to the plugin. For example in iTerm, solarized themes won't work until you set the theme of the terminal itself to Solarized.

Answer (score 0):

I only have the following configs in my **Vimfiles** and **airline** theme follows the main theme:

```
set laststatus=2
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `set background=dark` in your `.vimrc`

You can also try setting this in vim first with `:set background=dark`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).